# В чем стойкость симметричного шифрования?

Tags: blowfish, шифрование

Подключил blowfish к своему проекту. Посмотрел исходники и возник такой вопрос. Сам алгоритм blowfish довольно простой и по коду можно понять, что это blowfish, а не что-то другое. Вот, например, кто-то сделал архиватор на c# и добавил шифрацию по паролю. Если у того, кто захочет расшифровать архив, будет знание алгоритма (а его можно получить, декомпилировав c#), которым он зашифрован, может ли он, не зная пароля, расшифровать его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А в чём, тогда, по Вашему, смысл шифрования? В том и смысл, что не зная пароля, зашифрованные данные не расшифровать.

Естественно, самые простые алгоритмы, вроде «прибавить 2 к каждому байту исходных данных» легко взломать, если знаешь исходный код.

Но давайте рассмотрим, хотя бы, простейший алгоритм, вроде «прибавить n к каждому байту», где n — по сути, пароль. Знание точного алгоритма не позволит Вам напрямую расшифровать данные, поскольку всё ещё не хватает ключа. Но оно даст Вам подсказку, как подойти к расшифровыванию эффективнее.

Хорошее шифрование отличатся от плохого тем, что знание точного алгоритма шифрования не даёт абсолютно никаких преимуществ. Общеизвестные алгоритмы, вроде упомянутого Blowfish, которым уже много лет, много-много раз проверены на стойкость математиками. Не сомневайтесь, алгоритм надёжный :).

Answer (score 2):

Странный вопрос, практически все алгоритмы шифрования открыты, это же не означает что все ими зашифрованное можно легко расшифровать не зная пароля?! Скорее тут нужно говорить о конкретной реализации алгоритма blowfish, поскольку в нем могут быть закладки или просто ошибки, которые позволят выполнить атаку на шифрованный файл.
А если в общем случае, то ответ будет "Нет, нельзя расшифровать не зная пароля."